# index was out of range exception while collecting the certificates from store.localmachine

Tags: .net, x509certificate2

I have installed comodo digital certificate in my system and has written the following code in sharepoint visual web parts to send the email with digitally signed...

```
 private X509Certificate2 GetCertificate()
    {
        X509Store store = new X509Store(StoreName.My, StoreLocation.CurrentUser);
        store.Open(OpenFlags.OpenExistingOnly);          

        X509Certificate2Collection certificates = store.Certificates;
        X509Certificate2 certificate = certificates[0];

        return certificate;
    }
```

It is working fine when I run the application from my system that digitally signed mail is triggered..

At the same time..installed another comodo digital certificate in my colleague's system and tried to send the mail from his login...Mail is triggering but not digitally signed..It is saying that Index was out of range exception..

Can you please help me in tracing out this..

Comment: It means there are no certificates inside that store, or they're not visible by the running account.

Comment: I have modified StoreLocation.LocalMachine  and StoreName.TrustedPeople where I have imported my friend's certificate to Trusted People in the certificates of IE. But there is no use..

Answer (score 1):

There is only one array that I could see in the code and that is certificates which is assigned by the statement store.Certificates. So the array indexoutofbound exception can only come up when there are no certificates existing in the users machine that are available in the specified store. Did you put store.Certificates in watch window and found what value it has. My intuition is that it will be null. Can you please confirm?

Comment: Yes..It is showing count as 0 for that user ,Even though the certificates are there.

Comment: In that case, I would follow the steps in the below link and first manually verify if the certificate really exists or not. [link] (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms788967.aspx)

Comment: Yeah verified..but still same exception coming

Comment: Someone seems to be copying this thread on their website [link] (http://www.ggkf.com/net/index-was-out-of-range-exception-while-collecting-the-certificates-from-store-localmachine)

Comment: I would try the following. Check with the other attributes of OpenFlags and find out if any of those returns non-zero value for certificate count. If none returns non-zero value then I would simply log a request at Microsoft forum. Secondly, if any of those attributes returns non-zero value I will investigate what is the difference between that attribute and OpenExistingOnly property.   Note: I have worked at Microsoft in the past and I can say that some bug might have crept in but the support guys are really helpful and they will surely provide you with solution or a workaround to your issue.